# Регулярное выражение PHP для изменения url-адреса

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Всем привет. Есть текст в нем тег ссылки, нужно в href заменить параметр, отвечающий за язык. Пример:

```
Сегодня мы гуляли в <a href="http://site.ru/en/park/">парке</a>
```

Нужно заменить "en" на другой язык, например, на "ru". Язык всегда идёт после домена.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/.*?\/)en/i', '$1ru', $text)
```

Мне кажется как-то так.

Answer (score 2):

Я делаю так :

```
preg_replace ('#/ru/#','/en/',$url);
```

Comment: $url = '<a href="/english/parent/">парке</a>';

Comment: @lampa от причепа) шаблон же заведомо известен)

Comment: я об этом же ж

Comment: @lampa, упс (( Я случайно удалил ваш комментарий. Пардон. Напишите еще раз.

Comment: @Deonis да бывает. В общем-то человек спросил решение задачи с помощью регулярных выражений, т.к. присутствуют какие-то неизвестные аргументы. Т.е. в данном случае неизвестно название сайта. Регулярное выражение @Deus во-первых, составлено не правильно и будет добавлять слеши; во-вторых будет заменять все сочетания букв "en" в тексте, пример в первом комментарии. Ну а уже если https, то после "s" добавить вопросительный знак.

Comment: @lampa,обратите внимание на ограничители - #, в моем регул. выражении заменяется не две буквы на две буквы, а вся конструкция вместе со слешами.

Comment: @lampa, ваш ответ полностью адекватен. Мой же составлен правильно в данном контексте вопроса. Вы правы, случайное выражение типа hello,/en/glish man! тоже у меня попадет под раздачу.

Comment: @Deus амм, понятненько. Уже забываю о возможностях.